# How to substring WHERE in SELECT php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column kd_barang2 as an id in my table. The values is like this: 010000101.

I want to select the first 7 number (0100001) and then show it.

The script to select is like this:

```
$queryalat1="select * from tb_master
  where kd_barang2 = '".$data1['kd_barang2']."'
  && jenis_barang='alat habis pakai'
  Group by merk_barang";
```

and then I tried this kind of code

```
$queryalat1="select * from tb_master
  where SUBSTRING(kd_barang2,0,7) = '".substr($data1['kd_barang2'],0,7)."'
  && jenis_barang='alat habis pakai'
  Group by merk_barang";
```

but it failed, because it didn't show any data in my table.

Comment: Try `$queryalat1="select * from tb_master where kd_barang2 = '".substr($data1['kd_barang2'],0,7)."' && jenis_barang = 'alat habis pakai' Group by merk_barang";`

Comment: NEVER concatenate strings into SQL queries! Learn how to use parameters.

Comment: Is the ID field numeric or textual? If the ID field is numeric, substring will return nothing.

Comment: not true, php will happily substr a number and give the desired result: `echo substr(12345678, 1, 5) == 23456`

Comment: @pala_ I wasn't talking about PHP's substr, I was talking about MySQL's SUBSTRING function. Also MySQL gladly accepts && in place of AND, though I also would recommend using AND

Comment: ... why? he's using the php function. and the mysql one behaves the same way. `select substr(12345, 3) = 345`

Comment: @pala_ And he's using also MySQL's SUBSTRING, if you read the actual query. Actually the problem is with base: PHP is zero-based, MySQL one-based, so my comment was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using MySQL's `SUBSTRING` function with the wrong start value. In PHP `substr()` will start with zero, but in MySQL it starts with 1. So you need to use `SUBSTRING(kd_barang2, 1, 7)`

Comment: ohh i see, your solution really work.. :D
I didn't know mysql's substring start from 1... -_-
Thank you so much, guess i have to learn more...

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$queryalat1="select * from tb_master where LEFT(kd_barang2,8) = '".substr($data1['kd_barang2'],0,7)."' && jenis_barang='alat habis pakai' Group by merk_barang";
```

Comment: It should be `LEFT(kd_barang2, 7)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this..
$queryalat1="select * from tb_master
  where left(kd_barang2,7) = '".substr($data1['kd_barang2'],0,7)."'
  && jenis_barang='alat habis pakai'
  Group by merk_barang";